# Can fs.writeFile called in a file routed to express, middlewared by session, delete the session cookie?

Tags: node.js, express, session, filesystems, middleware

I routed a js file to the main js file using express and it's router middleware. Also each path is middlewared by session. After authentication, a get request which is received only when req.session.loggedIn exists, will execute on every request since the login.

But on a put request, it will execute once and then will be blocked by the authentication validator which is a middleware in both requests.

When commenting out the fs.writeFile block the cookie remains as expected, and put request are executed more than once.

Can fs.writeFile mess up cookies?

This is the problematic block:

```
fs.writeFile('./data/tasks.json', stringed, (err)=>{
        if(err){return console.log(err)}
        console.log('req.session from tasks put:',req.session)

    }, ()=>res.send(`Successfuly added task. `))
```

This is the validation middleware:

```
const validator = (req, res, next)=>{

console.log('req.session in validator:',req.session)

if(!req.session.loggedIn){
    return res.status(401).send('Please log in.')
}
    next()}
```

This is the session middleware:

```
app.use(session({
secret: ';klmkljhjkhn;jk',
cookie: {
        maxAge: 6000065456468476813541684864764561231,
    httpOnly: true,
    secure: false,
},
saveUninitialized: true,
resave: true,
}))
```

This is the routing middleware:

```
app.use('/tasks', validator, require('./routes/tasks'))
```

Comment: Can you show how the application is composed - where exactly the fs.writeFile is used, in which route? Also, why do you pass 2 callbacks to fs.writeFile?

Comment: https://github.com/OrenSayag/jb_28_hw
I thought the additional callback might solve the problem

Comment: Hey, I've posted an answer. I'm trying to elaborate on the topic by writing an article, but it's still a work in progress. If it's any help, here is a rough draft that you may find useful - sorry if I'm unable to get it in a better shape for now: https://github.com/rkaw92/articles/blob/master/sessions/Article.md

Answer (score 0):

The problem that you describe is not easily exhibited by the code [in your repository](https://github.com/OrenSayag/jb_28_hw) that you linked to in the comments. I was able to login and add 2 tasks successfully via POST, and then read them back, without losing the session data.

It is possible that you were having some timing-related issue with the 2 callbacks: `fs.writeFile()` takes 1 callback, so the *other* callback was never being executed; I was unable to verify this, since the code in git does contain this exact statement. Since `express-session` saves the session only when the response is sent, and it didn't happen here, it was likely timing out - so it's probable that:

- You started a request to POST `/tasks` - it loaded the empty session (*not logged in*)
- You then logged in, and that response finished
- Finally, the first request to POST `/tasks` ended - and `express-session` resaved the (empty) session, so it overwrote your logged-in session

This can be avoided if you disable `resave: true`.

To sum up: `fs.writeFile` is not causing session problems by itself, but can lead to requests which overwrite session state, especially in the presence of:

- callback bugs
- very long writes
- resave: true

Comment: Thanks for the informing article! The solution to my problem was disabling nodemon, which kills the server on each file change, which is what fs.writeFile just does. I'm so relieved!

Answer (score 0):

The solution to my problem was disabling nodemon, which kills the server on each file change, which is what fs.writeFile just does. I'm so relieved!